# Invalid ModelState with null parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Playing with the new WebAPI 2.0 RC1 prerelease bits... given this method:

```
[HttpPut("{sampleForm}/{id?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage PutSampleForm(SampleForm sampleForm, int? id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // handle invalid model
    }

    // Insert valid model into DB with EF

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

It is marked with nullable id, but if id is in fact null, the ModelState is flagged as invalid as well... is this expected, or is there something I can do to let the ModelState know it needs to ignore nullable parameters?

Comment: This looks like a bug in RC bits. The behavior of optional route variables has changed in post-RC bits though. In post-RC bits, you would need to have the parameter on the action as `int? id = null` otherwise route wouldn't match resulting in 404. For your current scenario, the workaround i can think of is to special check for presence of value for `id`

Answer (score 0):

yes you would use question mark on the property of your model also, like this:

```
private int? id {get; set;}
```

Comment: But its a passed parameter, not part of my model... maybe I need to dig more into what defines the Model, from which ModelState is determined.

Comment: what is sampleForm? you should be passing a model to the controller instead

Comment: SampleForm is my model, and a complex type.  The id, however, is not part of that model.